# How to disable validation from action in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

Can anyone tell me how can we disable validation from action? Actually, I wanted to disable validation dynamically based on certain condition from action. I don't know how can we do that? Please help me.

My For validator as below:

```
$this->setValidators(
        array(
            'search_text'     => new sfValidatorString(
                array('required'=>true), 
                array('required' => 'Please enter keyword')),
            'field_type'      => new sfValidatorString(
                array('required'=>true), 
                array('required' => 'Please select an option')),
        )
    );
```

I want to disable above validation in action dynamically.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `enable_validation` (or whatever name you want) option for your form. The form constructor accepts a $options array. In your action, you pass an array which would look like this : `array('enable_validation option' => false)`

Then, in your form, use the `getOption()` method to retrieve this option and set the validators accordingly.